# Creating a Magic Wand tool in a photo editing app? (just the same as photoshop app)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, image-editing

Is there any way to create the magic wand tool just like the one in the photoshop app with an easier approach to "chroma key" stuff? that's very complicated, I have searched a lot and got nothing that I could actually make it to work. Is there any library or an easier approach to achieve this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(yourOriginalCGImage, [0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0]) to mask the green color

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Could you explain a little bit more about it? I'd appreciate.

Comment: That Will return a cgimage after removing the color range in your array. [redMin,redMax,greenMin,greenMax,blueMin,blueMax]

Comment: If You would like to remove black pass all zeros. For white all 255

Comment: and will it work the same way as what get from magic wand?

Comment: To choose a color like a picker you will need to get the pixel color from your  view

Comment: Did you found the solution for your question?.Because even I am trying to find the answer for this so after lot research I found that we need to use seed fill algorithm but that algorith is filling the colour.If found any help full code or link please let me know. @Connor T